# Converting JSON with leaves and nodes to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string that looks like the one below – this is straight from the DB:

```
"{\"object\":\"value\",\"document\":{\"object\":\"document\",\"data\":{},\"nodes\":[{\"object\":\"block\",\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"data\":{},\"nodes\":[{\"object\":\"text\",\"leaves\":[{\"object\":\"leaf\",\"text\":\"here is some text\",\"marks\":[]}]}]}]}}"
```

This is the first time I see something like this. I can surely `JSON.parse` it but this leaves me with an object.

Is it a common thing to see somthing like this?
Is there a library for rendering this to HTML or do I have to write my own method to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to render it on the page – especially the `here is some text` value, but those vary depending on the JSON. I've never seen it before and am wondering if there is already a solution for this

Comment: Unless the response object properties in your response are some uniform standard, there likely isn't a plugin that will work fully. You would likely need to create your own parser or do a combination of `JSON.parse` with `for(var key in obj)` syntax to iterate through and add parsing logic.

Comment: So, you want to traverse the JSON to the `leaves` node and print all the elements?

Comment: @silentw This is probably the best explenation of my problem. Thanks for the words!

Comment: So, you should probably try to do it with recursion, like trees are normally traversed

Comment: Thanks for putting this on hold guys, that's extremely helpful!
Anyway – https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate is the answer to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the json structure is fixed, you can do something like this:

```js
const json = JSON.parse("{\"object\":\"value\",\"document\":{\"object\":\"document\",\"data\":{},\"nodes\":[{\"object\":\"block\",\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"data\":{},\"nodes\":[{\"object\":\"text\",\"leaves\":[{\"object\":\"leaf\",\"text\":\"here is some text\",\"marks\":[]}]}]}]}}");

const leaves = [];

json.document.nodes.forEach(
  n => n.nodes.forEach(
    node => node.leaves.forEach(
      leaf => leaves.push(leaf.text)
    )
  )
);

console.log(leaves);
```

Comment: The thing is that the structure is not fixed :/

Comment: Is there any property that persists? For example: find the array with the name `leaves`?

Comment: I can't figure it out really. It seems to be a JSON that's used for rendering text paragraphs. Not sure, maybe used in some online text editor or something.

Comment: @Ancinek If you don't know what's supposed to be the output, how should we know?

Comment: I just got this project without any comments. Was just wondering if this is a common structure or not. Never mind.

Comment: @Ancinek We don't know how this json structure is built or by what tool. That should be where I'd start looking to try and understand.

Comment: I’ve started. SO is my last resort.

Comment: @Ancinek We have no magic wand, so we can't help you further! :)